# How to remove extra/excess header from bootstrap table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card border-0 shadow">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Barangay)
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Confirmed)
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PUI)
                                </th>
                                <th style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PUM)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Barangay)
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Confirmed)
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PUI)
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align:center;">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PUM)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can't remove it although I tried using different styles of table.
Sorry for this dumb question for I am new to web development and ASP.Net MVC.
Please see image below for reference.
Thanks in advance for any help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LosFA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have an extra th tag in your code:

```html
 <th style="text-align:center;">
     Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PUM)
 </th>
 <th></th>  <!------------------delete this->
```

if your table have 5 head table columns and your table body have 4, the body expect 1 column and keeps the space

Comment: Sorry for that. I didn't actually see that until now. Thank you.